# Tag suggestion: webhook

Tags: discussion, tags

I was surprised to find there isn't a [webhook](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webhook) tag on the DevOps site. Is this something that should be added?

A [webhook](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webhook) tag could apply to many existing questions, including:

- [Jenkins GitHub Organization Metrics](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/jenkins-github-organization-metrics)
- [Jenkins Webhook Management](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8342/jenkins-webhook-management)
- [How can Bitbucket webhooks be invoked after they are deleted?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8660/how-can-bitbucket-webhooks-be-invoked-after-they-are-deleted)

Comment: what would its tag wiki and/or excerpt look like?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens At least 150 reputation is required in beta to create a tag. Shall we create this tag?

Answer (score 2):

I'd be against creating a generic tag like that.

When creating a tag here's roughly what question I ask myself:

- Does it help defining the question content ? => At some level, yes, with caveats detailed below
- Is it unique enough to bring value ? => I think no (idem, details below)
- Would someone follow this tag ? => I doubt someone will filter specifically for webhooks questions (or against them)
- What would I write as tag wiki ? => This is the most problematic part here

for the details: github, gitlab, jenkins, bitbucket (and others I don't think of right now) have each their own format and payloads so there'll be little in common between a question about Jenkins webhooks and bitbuckets webhooks.
This negatively impact the value the tag brings to the question and add complexity in writing its wiki description and usage guidelines.

While it still describe the content of the question, I don't feel it would really bring something useful to the site.